# How can I sum-up the values by each category in xsl?

Tags: xslt

I need summarize the sales by locations from our partner xml(do not know how many locations in advance):

sample input:

```
<company>
    <deparment dept="001">
        <location>
            <locationCode>001</locationCode>
            <sales>10000</sales>
        </location>
        <location>
            <locationCode>0005</locationCode>
            <sales>12500</sales>
        </location>
    </deparment>
    <deparment dept="002">
        <location>
            <locationCode>001</locationCode>
            <sales>40000</sales>
        </location>
        <location>
            <locationCode>004</locationCode>
            <sales>30000</sales>
        </location>
    </deparment>
    <deparment dept="003">
        <location>
            <locationCode>004</locationCode>
            <sales>60000</sales>
        </location>
    </deparment>
</company>
```

The expected output:

```
<location>
    <locationCode>001</locationCode>
    <totalSales>50000</locationCode>
<location>
<location>
    <locationCode>005</locationCode>
    <totalSales>12500</locationCode>
<location>
<location>
    <locationCode>004</locationCode>
    <totalSales>90000</locationCode>
<location>
```

Does xsl have something like group-by? I am new to xsl and appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Comment: What xsl version do you use? Xslt2.0 has xsl:for-each-group instruction

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work for xslt 1.0 with this.

```
<xsl:key name="Location" match="/company/deparment/location" use="locationCode"/>

<xsl:template match="company">
  <company>
  <xsl:for-each select="./deparment/location[generate-id() = generate-id(key('Location', ./locationCode)[1])]">
    <xsl:variable name="LocationCode" select="./locationCode"/>
    <location>
      <locationCode>
        <xsl:value-of select="$LocationCode"/>
      </locationCode>
      <totalSales>
        <xsl:value-of select="sum(//location[locationCode = $LocationCode]/sales)"/>
      </totalSales>
    </location>
  </xsl:for-each>
  </company>
</xsl:template>
```

Check out the [muenchian method](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html) for problems like this in the future.

Answer (score 1):

This would be a solution using XSLT 2.0:

For the following input XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<company>
    <department dept="001">
        <location>
            <locationCode>001</locationCode>
            <sales>10000</sales>
        </location>
        <location>
            <locationCode>0005</locationCode>
            <sales>12500</sales>
        </location>
    </department>
    <department dept="002">
        <location>
            <locationCode>001</locationCode>
            <sales>40000</sales>
        </location>
        <location>
            <locationCode>004</locationCode>
            <sales>30000</sales>
        </location>
    </department>
    <department dept="003">
        <location>
            <locationCode>004</locationCode>
            <sales>60000</sales>
        </location>
    </department>
</company>
```

Using the following XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output indent="yes" />
<xsl:template match="/company">
<company>
    <xsl:for-each-group select="department/location" group-by="locationCode">
        <location>
            <locationCode><xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/></locationCode>
            <totalSales><xsl:value-of select="sum(current-group()/sales)"/></totalSales>
        </location>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
</company>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I'm getting the output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<company xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <location>
        <locationCode>001</locationCode>
        <totalSales>50000</totalSales>
    </location>
    <location>
        <locationCode>0005</locationCode>
        <totalSales>12500</totalSales>
    </location>
    <location>
        <locationCode>004</locationCode>
        <totalSales>90000</totalSales>
    </location>
</company>
```

Answer (score 1):

**A short, simple and efficient XSLT 1.0 solution (no variables, no `xsl:for-each`)**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:key name="kLocById" match="location" use="locationCode"/>

 <xsl:template match=
  "location
    [generate-id()
    =
     generate-id(key('kLocById',locationCode)[1])
    ]">
  <location>
   <xsl:copy-of select="locationCode"/>
   <totalSales>
    <xsl:value-of select="sum(key('kLocById',locationCode)/sales)"/>
   </totalSales>
  </location>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<company>
    <deparment dept="001">
        <location>
            <locationCode>001</locationCode>
            <sales>10000</sales>
        </location>
        <location>
            <locationCode>0005</locationCode>
            <sales>12500</sales>
        </location>
    </deparment>
    <deparment dept="002">
        <location>
            <locationCode>001</locationCode>
            <sales>40000</sales>
        </location>
        <location>
            <locationCode>004</locationCode>
            <sales>30000</sales>
        </location>
    </deparment>
    <deparment dept="003">
        <location>
            <locationCode>004</locationCode>
            <sales>60000</sales>
        </location>
    </deparment>
</company>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<location>
   <locationCode>001</locationCode>
   <totalSales>50000</totalSales>
</location>
<location>
   <locationCode>0005</locationCode>
   <totalSales>12500</totalSales>
</location>
<location>
   <locationCode>004</locationCode>
   <totalSales>90000</totalSales>
</location>
```

**Explanation**: Appropriate use of the **[Muenchian method for grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html)** and template matching.

Comment: @user1252779: I am glad my answer was useful to you. Please, consider accepting the best answer (by clicking the check-mark next to the answer).

Answer (score 0):

For **Xslt 2.0** (with **xsl:for-each-group** instruction):

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="2.0" >

    <xsl:output indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each-group select="company/deparment/location" group-by="locationCode">
            <location>
                <locationCode><xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/></locationCode>
                <totalSales><xsl:value-of select="sum(current-group()/sales)"/></totalSales>
            </location>
        </xsl:for-each-group>

    </xsl:template>  

</xsl:stylesheet>
```